# Is there any SharePoint migration tool available that works on the web?

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-migration, migration

We are working on a project where we need save the money therefore, we cannot run migration tools on a dedicated machine.

Is there any SharePoint online to SharePoint online migration tool available in market that we can run on the web rather than downloading it to the local machine and then perform the migration?

Thanks

Comment: Trying to save on matches usually leads to disastrous results.

Answer (score 0):

Check mover.io, I've never used it personally but might suits your needs

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft provides it's own built in Migration Tool and that is part of the O365 offering now so it is free if you've already purchased your licenses.  You can read about it here -> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointmigration/how-to-use-the-sharepoint-migration-tool

Your mileage may vary with this tool depending on the complexity of your migration and where you are migrating content from.

Another option is PowerShell. PowerShell is free but you're going to have to put some work in to write scripts to do your migration - so technically not free as you will spend time writing those scripts and then writing more scripts to validate your migration.

I would recommend you spend the small amount on a license for a tool (just use your favourite search engine to search for "SharePoint Online Migration Tools") as it will save you some headaches in the short term if you use it correctly.